# Is there a security risk in exposing MySQL tables names in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security

I have an ajax method that esentially works like this

```
function getRow(tableName, idName, idValue, callback)
```

The obvious benefit of this is that I have one function that can retrieve data from any table. However, this just *feels* wrong from a security perspective, is it a security risk to do so? The corresponding PHP files that actually read/manipulate the database are secured through a prior authentication process, so theoretically, the visibility of table names in a vacuum shouldn't be a risk (not to mention that the database only accepts localhost connections), but I wonder if there isn't a better/prettier way to accomplish this.

Edit: Just to clarify the authentication process, user/role security prevents access to all tables except those explicitly allowed for the user.

Comment: What if I call this function with `syscolumns` as a parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're *sure* that you have no SQL injection vulnerabilities, and that you never will, it's fine.

If you do have a SQL injection vulnerability, it will make the attacker's job somewhat easier.

It goes without saying <sup>(I hope)</sup> that the server-side script must use a whitelist of tables and columns that can be exposed via this method.

Comment: I like that, somewhat easier, because if you have SQL injection vulnerability then finding table names is easy.

Comment: @mcdonald: If you can't get any output from the vulnerability, it makes it quite a bit easier.

Comment: +1, I agree with @SLaks. However (just a thought), knowing the names of table(s) just makes it just a tad bit easier for them, I think. What I usually do, just because I don't like people knowing things about whatever I have in the background (I.e. Tables, Databases, files etc), is I usually XOR the names of my tables and filenames. It's not meant to "Stop" or "Prevent" people from figuring it out, but it does make it just that bit harder for your average person to figure out names that are being used. But, you probably don't want the extra overhead that comes with having to XOR the names.

Comment: @JTS: If you're doing that, you might as well use a hard-coded lookup from table names to random strings on the server, so that the client never sees any real names.

Answer (score 3):

Tables names alone aren't that bad, however, the API you seem to be making may not be the best idea...

Think carefully about if there are some tables that people shouldn't be able to query, because from the looks of it, I could query any table in your database from the client side. For example:

```
getRow('users', 'id', '7', function(data){console.log(data)})
```

What if the users table returns their password? even if it is hashed, thats not good. Or their email? What if I want to harvest all of the users emails? Pretty easy script I could write to do that.

Comment: I **hope** that this is what he means by server-side authentication.

Comment: Exactly, hopefully the authentication doesn't stop at "can execute query!"

Answer (score 1):

You can show eg `users` table name in JS but on server side add prefix like `forum_users`, which will be actual table name in database. That way if someone finds injection point he will try `DROP TABLE users` and the query will fail, if you are lucky :)

Also add a white/black list for tables and columns, add LIMIT 1 (don't loop), don't return multiple arrays, and you should sanitize with something like this.

```
$select = preg_replace("#[\w]#", "", $_GET["select"]);
$from = preg_replace("#[\w]#", "", $_GET["from"]);
$where = preg_replace("#[\w]#", "", $_GET["where"]);
$equals = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["equals"]);

$query = "SELECT $select FROM $from WHERE $where = '$equals' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a risk because it provides information to attackers. It's the same as providing the software version of software that you are using. It is not a vulnerability per se, but it's a door to vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **really bad idea**.

For instance lets say you are using this code:

```
$table_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['table']);
$id_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['idname']);
$id_value=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['idvalue']);

mysql_query("select * from `$table_name` where `$id_name`='$id_value'");
```

This can be exploited a number of ways:

**NOT SQL Injection**

This query will return the root user in `mysql.user`, and this is

`?table=mysql.user&idname=user&idvalue=root`
This request will create the query:

`select * from`mysql.user`where`user`='root'`

**SQL Injection:**

This works because [mysql_real_escpae_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) does not escape back-ticks:``

```
?table=`table where 1 union select * from mysql.user/*&idname=junk&idvalue=junk
```

Comment: Yes, but MySQL table name can only contain `\w` characters, if I am not mistaken. But input should be validated.

Comment: @webarto no exposing functionality like this is just stupid.   You could obtain the password hash for another user on the same db without needing a period.

Answer (score 0):

A direct database API on the client-side should be used for very special cases of course. But you can safeguard it easily with a whitelist. In PHP for example:

```
if (in_array($tableName, array("users", "log", "messages", ...))) {
```

So I don't think it's that big of a deal from a security standpoint as long as you have a fixed list here.